# Need more swap space - out of disk slots

Tags: linux, mount, swap

A server I am using was setup incorrectly with only 1G of swap space.

There are no more hard disk physical slots.

There is content on the existing disks.

I would like to resize the partition, but that has been said to be "questionable" with `parted`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to increase the amount of swap space without loss of data?

NFS-mounting swap space is not an option :)

Comment: Could you say what kind of partitions do you use on your server, and how the partitions look like? Resize depends on the fs mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating a swap file rather than a swap partition:

Create the file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8192
```

Make it into swap:

```
mkswap /swapfile
```

Protect it:

```
chown root:root /swapfile
chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

Activate it:

```
swapon /swapfile
```

Activate each boot:

```
vi /etc/fstab
/swapfile1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: This is probably the most sensible solution. On modern linux systems, there's not much of a performance hit compared to a swap partition.

Comment: It solves the immediate problem without downtime so that the server can be scheduled in for restructuring the volumes at a business friendly time.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use gparted, not parted, which does not handle resizing the filesystems within the partitions.  There is a chance something can go wrong, but for the most part, it is quite reliable.  As always, have a backup.  BTW, had you set up the server initially using LVM, expanding the swap partition would be a snap.  Not only reliable, but also wouldn't even require any downtime.

Comment: +1 for the LVM suggestion: that's the better solution for handy scalability.

Answer (score 2):

You do not make it clear how much downtime you can afford on the server. If it is nothing too important, I suggest that you make a decent full backup of the server, store it on another machine, think thoroughly about how to restore your server from that backup in case everything goes wrong -- and then just go ahead and resize your partitions. Yes, that is always a bit risky, but I had an excellent success rate in the past years.

As a side note -- it would be good operating practice to always have a good backup handy, anyway. If you had that, this question would not arise ;-)